# Validate latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, validation, coordinates

I want to validate the latitude and longitude. Right now, I check just so that the value is not empty, but I want a validation to check that it is a valid latidue or longitude.

How do I do that?

My property looks like this:

```
public string Lat
{
    get {
        return this._lat; 
    }
    set 
    {
        base.ValidationErrors.Remove("Lat");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            this.ValidationErrors.Add("Lat", strings.Positions_Lat_Empty);
        }

        this._lat = value != null ? value.Trim() : null;
    }
}

public string Lng
{
    get { 
        return this._lng; 
    }
    set {

        base.ValidationErrors.Remove("Lng");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            this.ValidationErrors.Add("Lng", strings.Positions_Lng_Empty);
        }

        this._lng = value != null ? value.Trim() : null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you consider valid?  On the planet?  On land?

Comment: Why are you taking them as strings when they're naturally numbers?

Comment: Using string is not the best way i know that, but i can't change it now. I want to be sure it is sent as an approved coordinate and nothing else.

Comment: @Brad - valid are values that would reflect a position on the planet

Answer (score 71):

From MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578799.aspx

> Latitude measures how far north or
>   south of the equator a place is
>   located. The equator is situated at
>   0°, the North Pole at 90° north (or
>   90°, because a positive latitude
>   implies north), and the South Pole at
>   90° south (or –90°). Latitude
>   measurements range from 0° to
>   (+/–)90°.
>
> Longitude measures how far east or
>   west of the prime meridian a place is
>   located. The prime meridian runs
>   through Greenwich, England. Longitude
>   measurements range from 0° to
>   (+/–)180°.

[image]

In your setter for latitude, check if the value being set falls between -90 and 90 degrees.  If it doesn't, throw an exception.  For your longitude, check to see if the value falls between -180 and 180 degrees.  If it doesn't, throw an exception.

Comment: you can have negative lat/long. typically, the range is -90 to +90 and -180 to +180

Comment: @Muad'Dib, that article says you can have negative numbers... (that's what the (+/-) is), it's saying from -90 to +90 for Lat, and -180 to +180 for Long

Comment: Duckett He was right -- I had it wrong and changed my answer.

Comment: Duckett isn't that what i just said? :)

Answer (score 39):

Alternatively you can use [GeoCoordinate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.aspx) class that is built into .NET 4 (reference System.Device.dll). Its [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee426026.aspx) throws on invalid longitude and latitude:

> **latitude**
>
> Type: System.Double
>
> *The latitude of the location. May range from -90.0 to 90.0.*
>
> **longitude**
>
> Type: System.Double
>
> *The longitude of the location. May range from -180.0 to 180.0.*

Answer (score 26):

Use Doubles, rather than Strings. If you need to allow String input then use `Double.TryParse(string)`

```
    public Double Lat
    {
        get
        {
            return this._lat;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < -90 || value > 90)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Latitude must be between -90 and 90 degrees inclusive.");
            }
            this._lat= value;
        }
    }

    public Double Lng
    {
        get
        {
            return this._lng;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < -180 || value > 180)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Longitude must be between -180 and 180 degrees inclusive.");
            }
            this._lng= value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[typically latitude/longitude are decimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees), not a strings.

> Decimal degrees are an alternative to
>   using degrees, minutes, and seconds
>   (DMS). As with latitude and longitude,
>   the values are bounded by ±90° and
>   ±180° respectively. Positive latitudes
>   are north of the equator, negative
>   latitudes are south of the equator.
>   Positive longitudes are east of Prime
>   Meridian, negative longitudes are west
>   of the Prime Meridian. Latitude and
>   longitude are usually expressed in
>   that sequence, latitude before
>   longitude.